# Best way to do parallel stages?

Tags: c#, libgit2, libgit2sharp

I want to stage files in parallel and commit into different branches concurrently.

There will be multiple access at the same time. The repo.Index.Stage/repo.Commit API works on the same current directory so I think this is out of the question.

Can you guys give me some tips on how this might be achievable? A general idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a feasibility perspective, I can think of two different options:

**Considering the "stage files in parallel" as a constraint**

The word *"staging"* in git parlance implies the use of the index.

In order to stage in files in parallel, one could open many repository instances, each of them accepting a different pair of Working Directory/Index. All of them creating objects in the same object database.

This can be achieved thanks to the optional `RepositoryOptions` parameter of the `Repository` constructor.

See this **[this test](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/RepositoryOptionsFixture.cs#L101-L138)** in order to get a first glimpse at how this is achievable.

**Alternate proposal, Barebone Edition**

Another option is to *not* use the index and create objects directly in the object database. However, this means that nothing would be "staged", and that Blobs, Trees and Commits would have to created by hand.

A lower level API allows such kind of manipulations. This API would even allow one to *"commit"* against a bare repository.

See the **[ObjectDatabaseFixture](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/ObjectDatabaseFixture.cs)** and **[TreeDefinitionFixture](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/TreeDefinitionFixture.cs)** test suites for more information about how to achieve this.

This API will only create objects in the database. You will have to update the tip of the branches by yourself. This can be achieved thanks to the `Repo.Refs.Add()` and `Repo.Refs.UpdateTarget()` methods.

Comment: This what I have come up with, but I fear that when I create the same object two times that it will break somehow: https://gist.github.com/txdv/5474093

Comment: @AndriusBentkus You can safely create the same object (Commit, Tree, Blob) many times. Its content will be hashed. If the hash already exists in the object database, the existing object will be returned. No collision will happen.

Comment: @AndriusBentkus Was this answer helpful?

Comment: Yes it was! Thank you. I upvoted it, so I thought it would be clear that I found it helpful.

Comment: @AndriusBentkus Thanks for the upvote! Maybe could you accept it as well ;-) BTW, voting is anonymous (cf. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27534/see-who-is-upvoting-downvoting-my-question-answer)

Comment: Never realized I could do that, sorry.